# Converting a C# DataTable instance to xml that contains HTML or binary data

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

Hmmmm ...

Although it works in most cases, one column has html data in it.
It seems that doing this ...

```
   StringBuilder xmltarget = new StringBuilder();
   XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmltarget);
   tableData.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
```

... doesn't identify where this html or binary data exists and wrap the data in cdata tags as it should ...

Is there something i need to do to ensure the relevant checks are made and a working xml string is produced?

Comment: Where possible I want to avoid doing something that isn't flexible.
I am using this in conjunction with n ashx handler to stream / sync changed records in 2 databases.

This means I need something that I can use on any DataTable.
The other end is fine, I have no issues rebuilding the dataTable and saving the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatable, I assume that the column with the html in it is just a string? If so then you're going to have to wrap it with the CData tags yourself. I don't think there is any magic in .Net that will do this for you.

I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I gave up looking in the end, I posted this question all over the net and pretty much everyone had no idea how this could be done with a .Net class, i guess it really can't be done automatically. I did however do a spot of refactoring and the solution is about 30 lines of code for both the server and client code. (i'm streaming the resulting xml to a server where it goes in a database).

Answer (score 0):

Are the columns typed in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the `CreateCDataSection` function which is a member of `System.Xml.XmlDocument`. It's pretty straightforward.

You may have to convert the datatable to an xml document object prior to writing it out.

Comment: thats the problem though ... if the datatable contains html data / binary data (more an issue with html though) the call to dataTable.WriteXml(destination) fails so all I have is a datatable unless I decide to call open read on my command.

Comment: I currently get this error if the html contains a full stop "." ....

'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.